# Prevent user to execute Executable file in windows Operating system

Tags: windows, operating-system, executable-format

I have an executable file called "XXX" and I want to prevent user to execute this executable file, so i have used this [link](https://www.technipages.com/prevent-users-from-running-certain-programs) to solve the problem, and it's working fine.

https://www.technipages.com/prevent-users-from-running-certain-programs

But If user rename the executable files as something called "YYY", then they can able to execute the file in window.I am trying to use the Original full name of executable, but I couldn't find the exact result. Kindly help me to solve this problem..

Comment: Can this not be done using ACLs?

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying... i am not aware of ACLs concept.. can u share some link.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthz/access-control-lists